# How to get all cities or townships of selected country in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

As I found currently I can get nearby locations of selected region in Google Place API. I like to know how can I get all townships/distinct of selected region in Google Maps or Places API?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a code similar to the following to restrict the search to a certain country.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=your-key"></script>
    <label for="city">
         <input id="city" name="city">
    </label>

    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById('city');
        var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
         };
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input,options);
    </script>
```

More codes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. This will **not** get *all cities or townships of selected country*. Please delete.